# Fastlane error building iOS app even when legacy build system not used

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane

I am building an iOS app in XCode 13.1. In File->Workspace Settings, I've set the build system to New Build System. In build settings, I'm using Swift version 5. If I build my dev target in Xcode, it works fine. But when I build the same scheme in Fastlane v2.198.1, I get an error that says "The Legacy Build System will be removed in a future release". I don't understand this error because I don't have the legacy build system selected.

I've spent several hours searching for solutions. I've tried a few but nothing works. I should say that my project uses Realm (10.13.0), Alamofire (5.4.3) and SwiftLint (0.43.1). These are the latest versions as of today.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.